# VSCode Error when running tests causing 30 second delay everytime I run a test

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

Hopefully someone can help on this one. When using the vscode UI to run my tests, everytime there is a 30 second delay before the test run starts because of the below error that I see in the output panel. I have no idea what's causing it though.

My virtual environment is created through venv and it's name is .venv, and I can activate it just fine in the terminal, but it seems as though maybe vscode is running into an error trying to activate it?

[image]

Pasting the text as well for your reference, although I've changed the path to say "mypath" and the user name to say "me" :)

```
2023-06-25 11:57:42.306 [info] > . ./.venv/bin/activate && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py
2023-06-25 11:57:42.306 [info] shell: bash
2023-06-25 11:58:12.313 [error] getActivatedEnvironmentVariables [Error: Command failed: . /Users/mypath/.venv/bin/activate && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python /Users/me/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:409:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1121:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)] {
  code: null,
  killed: true,
  signal: 'SIGTERM',
  cmd: ". /Users/mypath/.venv/bin/activate && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python /Users/me/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py"
}
2023-06-25 11:58:12.354 [info] DAP Server launched with command: /Users/mypath/.venv/bin/python /Users/me/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter
```

Comment: You can now remove the image and fix the formatting as well. ;) Also, provide a [mcve]. That said, search online for the errors/output you receive, in quite a few cases, there are existing cases with similar questions.

Comment: Thanks so much Ulrich! I searched quite a bit but couldn't find anything unfortunately. Although I suppose now someone might google and find the answer in 2 seconds lol

Comment: I googled and couldn't find a matching issue ticket. I'd encourage you to [raise one on their GitHub](https://aka.ms/pvsc-bug). If you do, please provide as much information as you can, and [edit] a link into your question post here to your issue ticket.

Comment: Have you tried other virtual environments? Did you meet the same problem?